# What does these non-numbered Monogatari novel's chapter title means?

Tags: monogatari-series

Based on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monogatari_novels#English_volume_list), each English volume for the *Monogatari* novel book has its own **chapter title**, for example:

1. Chapter Zero
2. Chapter One
3. Chapter Two
4. Chapter Three
5. Chapter Four
6. Chapter Five
7. Chapter Six
8. Final Chapter
9. **Chapter Nixed**
10. **Chapter Snug**
11. **Chapter Idle**
12. **Chapter Change**
13. **Chapter Chaos**

Basically, I roughly understand what does 'Chapter Zero' to 'Final Chapter' mean, I assume it is just for chronological meaning.

However, what does 'Chapter **Nixed, Snug, Idle, Change, Chaos**' mean? Any meaning behind why it is named after those 'term'?

Why don't they just name it 'Chapter Seven' and so on? And for *Hanamonogatari*, *hana* (花) means "flower", but why is its chapter named 'Chapter Change' instead of 'Chapter Flower'?

Answer (score 6):

Obvious spoilers for *Monogatari*:

- Chapter Nixed / *Nekomonogatari Kuro*

  In *Nekomonogatari Kuro*, the inner, Black Hanekawa, wants to get rid of all of her problems such as her "family." The word "nix" means "dropping/getting rid of something", so you can make a connection there. However, my theory is this is the first time Hanekawa drops acting like she is an omnipotent being, especially the dialogue between Araragi and Hanekawa in the last episode. So I believe that is where this comes from.
- Chapter Snug / *Nekomonogatari Shiro*

  At the end of *Nekomonogatari Shiro*, Hanekawa finally was able to accept all of her problems and emotions thus resulting in inner peace for herself. The word "snug" means "something comfortable or warm". She finally feels comfortable for being herself and doesn't think it's a bad thing thanks to Araragi. Also, let's not forget the talk between her and Araragi in the last episode. Probably she was feeling "warm" if you know what I mean. Also as a funny note, Tiger burns her so there is also this "feeling warm" meaning.
- Chapter Idle / *Kabukimonogatari*

  Well, this one is a bit ironic. In *Kabukimonogatari*, Araragi, again, wants to save someone. The lucky person is Hachikuji this time. Thus he and Shinobu travel to the past. That is so far from being idle, right? Anyway, they save Hachikuji from accident thus causing a time paradox where "ghost Hachikuji" never mentions where is Shinobu in *Bakemonogatari* since she is not dead in the new timeline. Thus in this new timeline, Black Hanekawa kills Araragi since Shinobu is not present at that time. She was "idle".
- Chapter Change / *Hanamonogatari*

  Since this is one of my favourites, I will explain both the chapter and volume name. You see in *Hanamonogatari*, we are seeing the development of Kanbaru as a person while dealing with her past. She is finally dealing with her problems without the help of others ahem Araragi ahem. Well, he helps a bit, but not in a direct way. Anyway, my point is, we are witnessing her grown as a person like a blooming flower. So yea, that is the symbolism there. The word "change" also comes from there.
- Chapter Chaos / *Otorimonogatari*

  Well, I couldn't find a better word to describe this arc. Chaos. The problematic personality of Nadeko finally erupts thus causing the chaotic end result of the arc, namely, the death of our main cast. We are also seeing how Ougi really operates. Her whole aim to cause chaos in an enigmatic way for Araragi.

> But why?

Nisio **loves** this type of puns and symbolism. Nearly every arc name contains one such as *Hanamonogatari*, *Bakemonogatari*, *Nisemonogatari*, etc. Others on the other hand directly give hints about the arc such as Owarimonogatari or *Nekomonogatari*.